# Android socket principle and exception

Tags: java, android, sockets

i'm begginer with java socket in android. i'm have some problem and need help for solving them.

I'm connect to server Socket with bottom code and every thing is fine.  but when call disconnect method and try to connect again i faced with problem such `socket is null` or BufferedReader object always return null after disconnect and connect again. maybe my disconnect way is wrong. what is the best way for disconnect socket at some time like intrupt internet and connect again?

Here is my code for connecting and disconnecting socket.

```
public class HelperSocket {

public static Socket socket = null;
public static DataOutputStream writer = null;
public static BufferedReader reader = null;
public static DataInputStream inputStream = null;
public static final String SOCKET_ADDRESS = "aUrlForSocket";
public static final int SOCKET_PORT = 6000;
public static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 30000;
public static Thread clientThread;
public static boolean isConnected = false;

public static boolean connect() {
    Utils.Log("StartConnect");
    if (!isConnected) {
        clientThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(HelperSocket.SOCKET_ADDRESS);
                     socket = new Socket(address.getHostAddress(), SOCKET_PORT);

                    isConnected = true;
                    socket.setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

                    writer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                    while (HelperSocket.isConnected) {
                        Utils.Log("onWhile" + reader.hashCode());
                        try {

                            if (reader.readLine() != null) {
                                Utils.Log(reader.readLine() + "");
                            } else {
                                Utils.Log("getNullFromServer");
                                //data get null here :)
                                disconnect();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Utils.Log("ProblemOnReadData" + e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Utils.Log("SocketProblemAt connect:" + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        clientThread.start();
    }

    return true;
}

public static boolean disconnect() {
    isConnected = false;
    if (!clientThread.isInterrupted())
        clientThread.interrupt();
    if (socket != null) {
        Utils.Log("SocketAndAllObjectCleared");
        try {
            socket.shutdownInput();
            socket.shutdownOutput();
            socket = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       /* stream = null;
        reader = null;*/
    }
    return false;
}


}
```

I create a reciever in network connectivity change, and need to disconnect socket when device not connect to internet and connect again when internet connection established.

The receiver:

```
public class BroadcastChangeNet extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Utils.isNetworkConnected()) {
            HelperSocket.connect();
            Utils.Log("NetWorkConnect");
        } else {
            HelperSocket.disconnect();
            Utils.Log("NetWorkDisConnect");
        }
    }
}
```

Checking network situation:

```
 public static boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) ApplicationClass.context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (i == null)
            return false;
        if (!i.isConnected())
            return false;
        if (!i.isAvailable())
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You need to close the socket, not shut it down.  You're reading a line and then throwing it away. You need to have a look at the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: @EJP if i close the socket then can i reuse that? somwhere read if close socket can reopen that again.

Comment: You can't reuse it if you either shut it down or close it. You have to create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point  of view you simply need to create saprate Jave class, below is my code that i tested successfully,

```
import android.content.Context;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
 * Created by Kintan Patel on 01-08-2016.
 */
public class SocketConnection {
    private Socket socket = null;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    private SessionHelper helper;

    public String EstablishConnection(String token) {
   // token = your message that write on socket server
        String response;
        try {

            //socket = new Socket("192.168.0.24", 2129); // Testing Server
            socket = new Socket("Your IpAddress", PORT NO); 
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(token);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            response = br.readLine();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            return null;

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "Sorry Fail to connect";
            return null;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            // e.printStackTrace();

            response = "Sorry Fail to connect";
            return null;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "Server Break";
            return null;

        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Now from your main class simply create the object of SocketConnection  class and use EstablishConnection() method,

```
eg :

     SocketConnection connection = new SocketConnection();
         String token = "message that you want to write on server";
         String response = connecation.EstablishConnection(token);
```

if you want to use AsynkTask than below is AsynkTask code :

```
private class ActivationTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            SocketConnection connection = new SocketConnection();
            String token = "getActivation|" + params[0] + "|";
            return connection.EstablishConnection(token);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (s != null) {
                 Log.e("RESULT" , s);



            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks @kintanpatel. just a little question: if i close the socket, can i reopen and use again?

Comment: Yes, you can reopen it again.